Connectivity between a monitor with AMD FreeSync Premium connectivity with laptop
I have an Acer Nitro 5 laptop AN515-57-57MX with a Redmi G27 monitor.
My laptop has an HDMI which connects directly into dGPU (RTX 3050Ti), a DisplayPort over USB-C port which connects to iGPU. There are 2 ways to connect to the G27

I can use a HDMI - HDMI cable to connect and forget about FreeSync
I can use a USB-C to DisplayPort cable to connect to use FreeSync but cannot bypass Optimus.

I'm asking if there's anyway to use the laptop HDMI port but still can use the FreeSync technology on the monitor, thank you!
